# How to go back to page after submitting form using PHP

Tags: php, html

I am new in PHP and I am just doing a simple input form webpage. problem is that after the submission website goes to the blank page, I want it to go back to the original one. I have read here that it may be helped by adding header() to my code but it doesn't help. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> Sample Form </title>
    <link href = "stl.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="connect.php">
    <input class = "PaganForm" id = "name" type="text" name="name" value=""> 
    <input class = "PaganForm" id = "img" type="text" name="img" value=""> 
    <input class = "PaganForm" id = "dsc" type="text" name="dsc" value="">
    <input type="submit" id = "SubmitButton" > 
</form>
<?php
    header("Location: http://localhost/simple-form.php");
    exit;
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'cero_db';
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pg";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $newName = $row['Name'];
        $newLink = $row['Link'];
        $newDsc = $row['Description'];

        echo "<h1>".$newName."</h1>";
        echo "<img src = \"".$newLink."\" />";
        echo "<p>".$newDsc."</p>";
    }

?>
<body>
</html>
```

Here is connect.php:

```
<?php
$name = $_POST["name"];
$lnk = $_POST["img"];
$dsc = $_POST["dsc"];

$servername = 'localhost';
$username = 'root';
$password = '';
$database = 'cero_db';



$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);



$sql = "INSERT INTO pg (Name, Link, Description)
        VALUES ('".$name."', '".$lnk."', '".$dsc."')";
$conn->query($sql);

?>
```

Any suggestions?

P.S. I could not find any questions that helped me so if this is duplicate just link the original and I will delete this.

Comment: `Header()` should be added __after__ submission code.

Comment: THe problem is that your header() function is after some html. You cannot use header after you've outputed something. You need to find a way to put header all the way on top or use output buffering. This is widely discuss on SO

Comment: Change `action="connect.php"` to `action="simple-form.php"` because you're processing the form values on the very page where you placed the form

Comment: @u_mulder it still wont work because header need to be sent BEFORE any data is sent and OP have html code being sent before the header function

Comment: @elementzero23 there is no problem submiting a form to SELF.

Comment: @u_mulder It helped me thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
header("Location: simple-form.php");
```

You have to add this in `connect.php`, because your submit-button in the form will direct you to `connect.php`.

Your connect.php should look like this:3

```
<?php
   $name = $_POST["name"];
   $lnk = $_POST["img"];
   $dsc = $_POST["dsc"];

   $servername = 'localhost';
   $username = 'root';
   $password = '';
   $database = 'cero_db';

   $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);



   $sql = "INSERT INTO pg (Name, Link, Description)
           VALUES ('".$name."', '".$lnk."', '".$dsc."')";
   $conn->query($sql);

   header("Location: simple-form.php");
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I will write it here before it get clogged under comments:

you need to move your header function above anything that will be sent to the browser. Since you are sending some html before calling header, the headers are already sent with your html code.
read about it http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
it is widely asked on SO as well search for php header redirect

Therefore you need to handle the form beofre you send any output or use output buffering. I sugget you check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

You could also use javascript to send you user to the right place.

Answer (score 0):

Sample example for your code...

**simple-form.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Sample Form </title>
        <link href = "stl.css" rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <form method="post" action="connect.php">
            <input class = "PaganForm" id = "name" type="text" name="name" value="">
            <input class = "PaganForm" id = "img" type="text" name="img" value="">
            <input class = "PaganForm" id = "dsc" type="text" name="dsc" value="">
            <input type="submit" id = "SubmitButton" >
        </form>
    <body>
</html>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
    $servername = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'cero_db';
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,$database);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM pg";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $newName = $row['Name'];
        $newLink = $row['Link'];
        $newDsc = $row['Description'];

        echo "<h1>".$newName."</h1>";
        echo "<img src = \"".$newLink."\" />";
        echo "<p>".$newDsc."</p>";
    }

    header("Location: simple-form.php");
    exit;
?>
```